# Ionic 4 Push Notification With One Signal not received any notification when i'm chat with same person

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, onesignal

Hi there? I'm in the problem. I'm finding a way to not display a notification when I'm on chat screen like if I chat somebody so do no any notification received against this user.

i'm using ionic 4 one signal plugin.

```
    import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal/ngx';

    constructor(private oneSignal: OneSignal) { }

    ...

    this.oneSignal.startInit('b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba', '703322744261');

    this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
     // do something when notification is received
    });

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
      // do something when a notification is opened
    });

    this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

Please help me. find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simon Grimm at [Devdactic.com](https://devdactic.com/) is a great Ionic resource. He has a tutorial to integrate OneSignal push notifications into an Ionic app. A step by step video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j0Jz5ka5Co&app=desktop) and the blog is [here](https://devdactic.com/push-notifications-ionic-onesignal/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Here, he did not show how to deal when we are on chat screen.

Comment: At 20:47 into video you can see how the OneSignal push notification functions in the app. This notification alert example is the primary use for this service. Are you trying to develop a chat app? [Here](https://devdactic.com/ionic-realtime-socket-io/) is a good resource from Simon.

Comment: I manage from backend. like i send a message i'm on chat screen when i leave then send message again i'm not no schat screen. that's logic works for me.